# Hover Intent plugin with different mouse enter and mouse leave

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I am using Hover indent plugin, This have only one function to combine mouse hover and mouse leave

Code1:

```
$("#tab").hoverIntent({
over: show, 
timeout: 20, 
out: hide
});
function show(){
$(".part").show();
}
function hide(){
$(".part").hide();
}
```

need write mouse leave function for .part, so made like this

Code2:

```
$("#tab").hoverIntent({
over: show, 
timeout: 20, 
out: hide
});
function show(){
$(".part").show();
}
$(".part").hoverIntent({
over: show, 
timeout: 20, 
out: hide
});
function hide(){
$(".part").show();
}
```

but it seems error... how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove any functions, because in `hoverintent()` the both `show()`  and `ehide()`  functions are used, make that function with empty like this

```
$("#tab").hoverIntent({
     over: show, 
     timeout: 20, 
     out: hide
});
function show(){
   $(".part").show();
}
function hide(){
}

$(".part").hoverIntent({
   over: show1, 
   timeout: 20, 
   out: hide1
});
function show1(){
}
function hide1(){
    $(".part").hide();
}
```

you must use different function names each show(),hide(),show1(),hide1() like this... try this